# iPad design issue when turns portrate mode to landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad, responsive-design, landscape-portrait

I have one issue regarding ipad design i use one slider in to that when i turns mode portrate to landscape then it is not taking width of landscape 
It takes width of Portrate mode and we have to reload the site to see perfect in to landscape mode i don`t want to reload site can anyone help me out form this issue

Answer (score 0):

Use proper meta tags in your header. Try this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Hello Surjit i am use wordpress and use one plugin and when i try to change mode then that plugin width is not changed i have to reload this page

Comment: what can i add then replacing 768px ?

Comment: Its not working mate are you on skype ? can you give me ur skype id ?

Comment: No Skype here. Lets chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign

Comment: Mate i cant able to chat there because i am new user and i have only one reputation and for chat need minimum 20 reputations so can you have any other communication like gmail or anything